# Is there a way to set the Render Order of Routes?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Basically, I want to render a [`ModalRoute`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute/buildPage.html) that is dependent on some widget in the route below it.

To achieve that I am using a `GlobalKey` which I attach to a widget in the lower route:

```dart
/// in LOWER route (widget that is in lower route)
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    key: globalKey,
    child: ..,
  );
}

/// UPPER route (different class!)
/// called using a function on tap in the lower route widget
/// `showModalRoute(globalKey)` 
@override
Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
  final renderBox = globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
  final Size size = renderBox.size;
  return SizedBox(
    width: size.width,
    height: size.height,
    child: ..,
  );
}
```

I am trying to make this respond to **orientation changes**. The widget in the lower route changes size when the orientation changes. 
The problem here is that the *upper route* seems to be built before the *lower route*. Maybe this is not the case, however, the **`size`** is always the previous size, i.e. I get the landscape size when rotating to potrait and vise versa as if the upper route was built before the lower route (my assumption). The same applies to the position. I basically get the *previous `RenderBox`*.

Is there any way for me to get **the current** position of my widget, i.e. via `renderBox.localToGlobal(0, 0)`? I imagine that I could achieve this by having the **`buildPage`** render after the `GlobalKey` has the new size.

Comment: `Is there any way for me to get the current size of my widget?` no, by definition that's not possible. Can you explain more your use-case?

Comment: @RémiRousselet Specifically, I mean the position (I achieve this using `renderBox.localToGlobal(0, 0)`, I also updated my question). I want to draw an overlay at the position of another widget.

Comment: Can you make a gif showcasing the exact desired behavior? Just to make sure that we're not in the XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @RémiRousselet It might be the case. I just want to display an overlay at the position of a widget and that overlay should disappear when tapping outside of it. I solved this using a `PopupRoute`, however, the position lags behind when changing the orientation, i.e. the overlay in `buildPage` gets rebuilt before the `renderBox` has the new position.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot if you want to simply limit popup's size - I did a similar thing by constraining it's max size to 90% width & height of the screen, plus limiting it's width to a certain static number so it won't look stretched and making the height being auto-sized. Lmk if that's the goal and I'll share my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code tell me if it worked as you expected

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

StreamController<MyWidgetStatus> firstRouteStatus =
    StreamController.broadcast();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Orination Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  GlobalKey _stateKey;
  MyWidgetStatus _status;
  double height;
  double width;

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    _stateKey = GlobalKey();

    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_calculatePositionOffset);

    super.initState();
  }

  _calculatePositionOffset(_) {
    _status = _getPositions(_stateKey);

    firstRouteStatus.add(_status);
    print("position = ${_status.position}");
  }

  MyWidgetStatus _getPositions(_key) {
    final RenderBox renderBoxRed = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final position = renderBoxRed.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    final height = renderBoxRed.constraints.maxHeight;
    final width = renderBoxRed.constraints.maxWidth;
    return MyWidgetStatus(position: position, width: width, hight: height);
  }

  void didChangeMetrics() {
    print("Metrics changed");
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_calculatePositionOffset);
    super.didChangeMetrics();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
          onPressed: () {
            _settingModalBottomSheet(context);
          }),
      body: OrientationBuilder(
        builder: (context, orientation) {
          return Center(
            child: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (context, constraints) => SizedBox(
                    key: _stateKey,
                    height: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 100.0 : 50,
                    width: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 50.0 : 100.0,
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _settingModalBottomSheet(context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext bc) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: StreamBuilder(
              stream: firstRouteStatus.stream,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<MyWidgetStatus> snapshot) =>
                  snapshot.hasData
                      ? Container(
                          child: Text("Position = ${snapshot.data.position}"),
                        )
                      : Text("No Data"),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}

class MyWidgetStatus {
  final Offset position;
  final double hight;
  final double width;

  MyWidgetStatus({
    this.position,
    this.hight,
    this.width,
  });
}
```

Edit: if you need the information to be rendered at the beginning you can use a BehaviorSubject instead of the native StreamController like

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
StreamController<MyWidgetStatus> firstRouteStatus =
   BehaviorSubject();
```

you also have to add the RxDart package in pubspec.yaml it is 0.22.0 at the time of writing this line.

```
rxdart: ^0.22.0
```

Comment: Superb answer! What I took away from this answer is [`ScheduleBinding.addPostFrameCallback`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html), which is what I searched for. I will accept this answer for now and you will automatically receive the bounty if nothing changes. However, Rémi Rousselet pointed out that there might be a different way to tackle this problem altogether.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot thanks a lot,I think you will need WidgetsBindingObserver and didChangeMetrics also because rotation does not triggers initState and the call back will execute only once,I am aware that you can use it directly to get the position from the other route without using a stream but, I prefer to implement like that as a first step to use it within the Bloc pattern, it will be great if Rémi Rousselet tackles the problem in a different way.